# C++ struct

Tags: c++, c++11

> struct Edge{  int to, cost;   
>   Edge(){}
>   Edge(int to, int cost):to(to),cost(cost){} };

これはどういった意味でしょうか？
Edge(){}は関数でしょうか

Comment: 上は https://www.ioi-jp.org/joi/2016/2017-yo/2017-yo-t6/sol/2017-yo-t6-sample.cpp の一部抜粋です(https://atcoder.jp/contests/joi2017yo/tasks/joi2017yo_f の回答例）

Answer (score 1):

***Edge(){}は関数でしょうか***

コンストラクタです。C++では、「戻り値型なし、関数名が型名と一緒」のメンバー関数宣言はコンストラクタとなります。`()`は引数無し、`{}`はコンストラクタ内での実際の処理が無いことを表しています。(次の行は引数ありのコンストラクタです。)

ちゃんとした(?)C++のコードから入られたのなら見慣れないかもしれませんが、C++を基本から解説している書籍やサイトをご覧になってみれば、このような書き方になっているものがたくさん見つかるかと思います。

ご自身がどの程度までC++の知識を持ち合わせているのかご披露いただければ、もう少し何か付け足せるかもしれません。

Comment: 一応　c++　を一通りクラスなども含めて勉強したのですがあまりコンストラクタを使ったこともなく（利点がよくわからなかった）、競プロのソースコードを勉強していたら見慣れないstructにさらに見慣れないコンストラクタがあったのでどういう役に立つのか分からない状態です。（structはほとんど勉強した覚えはありません）

Comment: なんとなくの勘なのですがEdge(){}とEdge(int to, int cost): to(to),cost(cost{}};と二つが有りますが、前者はなくてもよいのではないのでしょうか。また、うろ覚えの記憶なのですが、コンストラクタにもコピーなどの種類があるようです。これは何コンストラクタなのでしょうか？

Comment: 正直に書くと「structはほとんど勉強した覚えはありません」だと、「ほとんど何も勉強していないんだな」と思われることになるでしょう。C++ではclassとstructの違いなんてほとんどないので、structを全く使わなくてもコードは書けるんですが、メンバーがデフォルトでpublicという特性から「(可視性の制御なんて気にしなくて良いような)短期的・局所的なデータ構造の表現用」として使う人が多いようです。で、他のコンストラクタを定義すると、`Edge()`のような引数なしのコンストラクタ(デフォルトコンストラクタ)が無いと言うことになり、いろいろ不便なことも出てくるので普通は定義することが多い、と言ったところでしょうか。「うろ覚え」ではなくなる程度まではきちんとした入門書を読まれて、また質問することをお勧めしておきます。(「C++をマスターしたい」という特別なモチベーションがないんなら、また別ですが。)